# Gas + balance invariant not maintained on simple contract call

Tags: contract-development, truffle, javascript, testing, truffle-test

In order to understand reentrancy attacks, I'm using the following Honeypot contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

/// @title ReentrancyPot - A contract vulnerable to reentrancy
contract ReentrancyPot {
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    /// @dev Constructor.
    function ReentrancyPot() public payable {
        deposit();
    }

    /// @dev Deposit money into the contract
    function deposit() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    }

    /// @dev Receive payments
    function withdraw() public {
        if (!msg.sender.call.value(balances[msg.sender])()) {
            throw;
        }
        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm running the following tests using truffle test with the first assertion passing but the second not passing. It seems that this would break obvious contract + gas invariants. Can you help me understand what may be going wrong here?

```
var ReentrancyPot = artifacts.require("./ReentrancyPot.sol");
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'ws://localhost:8545');
var BN = web3.utils.BN;

require('chai')
 .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
 .should();

contract('ReentrancyPot', function(accounts) {
    it("pot should support deposits and withdrawals", async () => {
        let pot = await ReentrancyPot.deployed();
        let depositAmount = web3.utils.toWei('0.001', 'ether');
        let address = pot.address
        let gasPrice = web3.utils.toBN(await web3.eth.getGasPrice());

        let startingBalance = web3.utils.toBN(await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]));
        let startingBalanceContract = web3.utils.toBN(await web3.eth.getBalance(address));

        let result = await pot.deposit({from: accounts[0], value: depositAmount});
        let gasUsed1 = web3.utils.toBN(result.receipt.gasUsed);

        let endingBalance = web3.utils.toBN(await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]));
        let endingBalanceContract = web3.utils.toBN(await web3.eth.getBalance(address));

        endingBalanceContract
            .sub(startingBalanceContract)
            .toString()
            .should.equal(depositAmount);

        endingBalance
            .add(web3.utils.toBN(depositAmount))
            .add(gasUsed1.mul(gasPrice))
            .toString()
            .should.equal(startingBalance.toString());
    })
})
```

Comment: You should add gasUsed * gasPrice, not only gasUsed.

Comment: Hi @Ismael, I've made this correction, but unfortunately the second assertion still does not pass.

Comment: You have to use the gasPrice from the transaction receipt no the one returned by the network.